# Windows Performance Monitor fails to record <All Instances> of selected Process counters, and just records _Total

Tags: windows, perfmon

I'm attempting to configure a DataCollector set of counters, and would like to (and do) select `Process\% Processor Time\<All instances>`.  However, the resultant perfmon data counter collected is `_Total`.  How do I actually record the dynamic counter collection `<All instances>`?

Comment: While Brian's answer is right, I'd like to add some info before you think you went crazy.
This works entirely the opposite way on Windows client and server editions.
For example, on Windows 10 the Report shows all instances by default - just how you selected at the Data collector -, while on Windows Server 2019, you have to Add those counters AGAIN under your Report - just like how Brian showed.
I guess Microsoft is trying to be smarter again, and probably could explain why this is a feature, not a bug. Right, M$?
So @brandeded, it isn't you, who should be humbled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce your problem but do note the default report may lead somebody to think only `_Total` was collected.

[image]

The default report will show _Total counters but you can add more including `<All Instances>`.

[image]

Comment: You're correct!  I was trying to be too efficient and didn't look at `Add Counters`!  Cost me 50 internet points to be humbled, but sincerely thank you!

Comment: I noted that sometimes the "Instances of selected object" box is (confusingly) blank, even when I thought I had captured all instances of the Procss counter. To populate the box, just type in a few letters into the combo box below and click the "Search" button - that will populate the "Instances" box, allowing you to highlight them and click "Add >>".

Comment: @mbrownnyc Thanks for being humbled so that the rest of us don't have to be - even years later!

Comment: I am facing this same issue, although I have selected <all instances>, the report just shows me the _Total. I am expecting the report should show the counter for each process rather than _Total. How can I do this please?